# User-made pattern in tikz: the lines are dashed by default

Tags: latex, tikz

I want to fill an area of a figure with lines in tikz while specifying the angle. I used the method presented by the Pattern library https://tikz.dev/library-patterns but the user-specified pattern always give me dashed line.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[pattern={horizontal lines},pattern color=orange]
 (0,0) rectangle +(1,1);
 \draw[pattern={Lines[yshift=.5pt]},pattern color=blue]
 (0,0) rectangle +(1,1);

 \draw[pattern={vertical lines},pattern color=orange]
 (1,0) rectangle +(1,1);
 \draw[pattern={Lines[angle=90,yshift=-.5pt]},pattern color=blue]
 (1,0) rectangle +(1,1);

 \draw[pattern={north east lines},pattern color=orange]
 (0,1) rectangle +(1,1);
 \draw[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt/sqrt(2)}]},pattern color=blue]
 (0,1) rectangle +(1,1);

 \draw[pattern={north west lines},pattern color=orange]
 (1,1) rectangle +(1,1);
 \draw[pattern={Lines[angle=-45,distance={3pt/sqrt(2)}]},pattern color=blue]
 (1,1) rectangle +(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I expected, according to the example:

[image]

Here is what I got:

[image]

I use the VSCode PDFviewer and here is the log file generated by VSCode.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (prel
oaded format=pdflatex 2023.6.12)  4 OCT 2023 14:29 entering extended
mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  file:line:error style messages
enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
**"c:/Users/sarah/Documents/Scolarite/5_These/CRAS/version courante/Untitled-1.tex"
(c:/Users/sarah/Documents/Scolarite/5_These/CRAS/version
courante/Untitled-1.tex LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1 L3
programming layer <2023-05-15>
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option) )
\c@part=\count185 \c@section=\count186 \c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188 \c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190 \c@figure=\count191 \c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48 \belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16 \pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen141
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen142 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )) Package: pgf 2023-01-15
v3.1.10 (3.1.10) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration )
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107. 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex ))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen143 \Gin@req@width=\dimen144 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18 \pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20 )) \pgf@x=\dimen145 \pgf@y=\dimen146
\pgf@xa=\dimen147 \pgf@ya=\dimen148 \pgf@xb=\dimen149
\pgf@yb=\dimen150 \pgf@xc=\dimen151 \pgf@yc=\dimen152
\pgf@xd=\dimen153 \pgf@yd=\dimen154 \w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2 \c@pgf@counta=\count193 \c@pgf@countb=\count194
\c@pgf@countc=\count195 \c@pgf@countd=\count196 \t@pgf@toka=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks22 \t@pgf@tokc=\toks23 \pgf@sys@id@count=\count197 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) ) Driver file for pgf:
pgfsys-pdftex.def 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count198
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count199 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) ))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration ) Package
xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227. 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line
1353. Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357. Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line
1369. Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371. Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on
input line 1372. Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by
`hsb' on input line 1373. Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted
by `hsb' on input line 1374. Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray'
substituted by `gray' on input line 1375. Package xcolor Info: Model
`wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376. )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen155 \pgfmath@count=\count266 \pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks24 \pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks26 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count267 ))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen156 \pgf@picmaxx=\dimen157 \pgf@picminy=\dimen158
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen159 \pgf@pathminx=\dimen160 \pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen161
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen162 \pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen163 \pgf@xx=\dimen164
\pgf@xy=\dimen165 \pgf@yx=\dimen166 \pgf@yy=\dimen167
\pgf@zx=\dimen168 \pgf@zy=\dimen169 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen170 \pgf@path@lasty=\dimen171 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen172
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen173 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53 \pgf@hbox=\box54 \pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count268 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen174 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen175 \pgf@pt@y=\dimen176 \pgf@pt@temp=\dimen177 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen178 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen179 \pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count269
\pgf@shadingcount=\count270 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen180 \pgf@nodesepend=\dimen181 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) ))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) \pgffor@iter=\dimen182
\pgffor@skip=\dimen183 \pgffor@stack=\toks27 \pgffor@toks=\toks28 ))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count271 \pgfplotmarksize=\dimen184 )
\tikz@lastx=\dimen185 \tikz@lasty=\dimen186 \tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen188 \tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen189
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen190 \tikzleveldistance=\dimen191
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen192 \tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59 \tikz@tempbox=\box60 \tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count272 \tikznumberofchildren=\count273
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count274 \tikz@fig@count=\count275 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count276 \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count277
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count278 ) \tikz@expandcount=\count279 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) )))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output
(pdfTeX) \l__color_backend_stack_int=\count280
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box62 ) (Untitled-1.aux) \openout1 =
`Untitled-1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:  
... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input
line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:
Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:   
... okay on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input
line 3. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3. 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count281 \scratchdimen=\dimen193 \scratchbox=\box63
\nofMPsegments=\count282 \nofMParguments=\count283
\everyMPshowfont=\toks29 \MPscratchCnt=\count284
\MPscratchDim=\dimen194 \MPnumerator=\count285
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count286 \everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks30 )
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on
input line 485. 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for
MiKTeX ))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) 
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex
File: pgflibrarypatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10) ))
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibrarypatterns.meta.code.tex
(C:\Users\sarah\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibrarypatterns.meta.code.tex))
[1

{C:/Users/sarah/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(Untitled-1.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  12106
strings out of 476411  260495 string characters out of 5789134 
1851845 words of memory out of 5000000  32285 multiletter control
sequences out of 15000+600000  512287 words of font info for 32 fonts,
out of 8000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 
102i,5n,104p,474b,571s stack positions out of
10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/sarah/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on Untitled-1.pdf (1 page, 12504 bytes). PDF
statistics:  22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  0 named
destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  45 words of extra memory for
PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Could you please tell me how to get solid lines?

Comment: Have you seen [tex.se]?

Comment: Can you show your .log file and tell which pdf viewer you use? I get solid lines when running your code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTTEl.png

Comment: Your comment made me think to open the PDF in an other app (Adobe Acrobat Reader) than the PDF viewer that I use (the VSCode one) and the lines appear solid there indeed.